# Using kinesis async client AWS SDK 2 with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to use the KinesisAsyncClient as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-kinesis-src-main-java-com-example-kinesis-KinesisStreamRxJavaEx.java.html

I have a mac OS and I have configured the following dependencies for async http client

'software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:2.16.101'
'software.amazon.awssdk:kinesis:2.16.99'

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/internal/tcnative/SSLPrivateKeyMethod

```
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.AwaitCloseChannelPoolMap.newPool(AwaitCloseChannelPoolMap.java:119)
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.AwaitCloseChannelPoolMap.newPool(AwaitCloseChannelPoolMap.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.SdkChannelPoolMap.get(SdkChannelPoolMap.java:44)
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.createRequestContext(NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.java:140)
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.execute(NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.java:121)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder$NonManagedSdkAsyncHttpClient.execute(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:463)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.doExecuteHttpRequest(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:219)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.executeHttpRequest(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:191)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$execute$1(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:100)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.execute(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:96)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.execute(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:61)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(AsyncApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:55)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(AsyncApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:37)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.attemptExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:110)
```

In the same example folders, the syncClient works well and connects to kinesis on AWS. Does anyone know what can be done to fix this?

Comment: I am looking into this

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code:

```
package com.example.kinesis.asny;


import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.SdkPublisher;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.ShardIteratorType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.StartingPosition;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.SubscribeToShardEvent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.SubscribeToShardRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.SubscribeToShardResponseHandler;
import software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap;


public class KinesisStreamRxJavaEx {

    private static final String CONSUMER_ARN =  "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:814548xxxxxx:stream/LamDataStream/consumer/MyConsumer:162645xxxx";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KinesisAsyncClient client = KinesisAsyncClient.create();

        SubscribeToShardRequest request = SubscribeToShardRequest.builder()
                .consumerARN(CONSUMER_ARN)
                .shardId("shardId-000000000000")
                .startingPosition(StartingPosition.builder().type(ShardIteratorType.LATEST).build())
                .build();

        responseHandlerBuilder_RxJava(client, request).join();

        System.out.println("Done");
        client.close();
    }


    /**
     * Uses RxJava via the onEventStream lifecycle method. This gives you full access to the publisher, which can be used
     * to create an Rx Flowable.
     */
    private static CompletableFuture<Void> responseHandlerBuilder_RxJava(KinesisAsyncClient client, SubscribeToShardRequest request) {

        // snippet-start:[kinesis.java2.stream_rx_example.event_stream]
        SubscribeToShardResponseHandler responseHandler = SubscribeToShardResponseHandler
                .builder()
                .onError(t -> System.err.println("Error during stream - " + t.getMessage()))
                .onEventStream(p -> Flowable.fromPublisher(p)
                        .ofType(SubscribeToShardEvent.class)
                        .flatMapIterable(SubscribeToShardEvent::records)
                        .limit(1000)
                        .buffer(25)
                        .subscribe(e -> System.out.println("Record batch = " + e)))
                .build();
        // snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.stream_rx_example.event_stream]
        return client.subscribeToShard(request, responseHandler);

    }

    /**
     * Because a Flowable is also a publisher, the publisherTransformer method integrates nicely with RxJava. Notice that
     * you must adapt to an SdkPublisher.
     */
    private static CompletableFuture<Void> responseHandlerBuilder_OnEventStream_RxJava(KinesisAsyncClient client, SubscribeToShardRequest request) {
        // snippet-start:[kinesis.java2.stream_rx_example.publish_transform]
        SubscribeToShardResponseHandler responseHandler = SubscribeToShardResponseHandler
                .builder()
                .onError(t -> System.err.println("Error during stream - " + t.getMessage()))
                .publisherTransformer(p -> SdkPublisher.adapt(Flowable.fromPublisher(p).limit(100)))
                .build();
        // snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.stream_rx_example.publish_transform]
        return client.subscribeToShard(request, responseHandler);
    }
    
}
```

It successfully completed:

[image]

Make sure that you specify a valid consumer ARN value; otherwise the code does not work.

You can get a valid consumer ARN using this code;

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.KinesisException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.RegisterStreamConsumerRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.RegisterStreamConsumerResponse;

public class RegisterStreamConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    ListShards <streamName>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    streamName - The Amazon Kinesis data stream (for example, StockTradeStream)\n\n" +
                "Example:\n" +
                "    ListShards StockTradeStream\n";

        //  if (args.length != 1) {
        //      System.out.println(USAGE);
        //      System.exit(1);
        //  }

        String streamARN = "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:8145480xxxxx:stream/LamDataStream" ; //args[0];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        KinesisClient kinesisClient = KinesisClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();


       String arnValue =  regConsumer(kinesisClient, streamARN);
       System.out.println(arnValue);
        kinesisClient.close();
    }

    public static String regConsumer(KinesisClient kinesisClient, String streamARN) {

        try {
            RegisterStreamConsumerRequest regCon = RegisterStreamConsumerRequest.builder()
                    .consumerName("MyConsumer")
                    .streamARN(streamARN)
                    .build();


            RegisterStreamConsumerResponse resp = kinesisClient.registerStreamConsumer(regCon);
            return resp.consumer().consumerARN();

        } catch (KinesisException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at my problem. What is the version of JDK you are using? I am using 11.0.2 openjdk. Also I am using MAC os . Can you tell me list of dependencies you added to run this code successfully. That would truly help me. I created the consumer ARN using command line as follows ```aws kinesis register-stream-consumer --stream-arn "XYZ" --consumer-name indexer```

Comment: I am using 1.8 JDK. The POM with the dependencies is here:  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/kinesis

Comment: Is it possible to try with openJDK 11 which I am using.. Trying to update the dependencies and run again. The weird part with many other small env variables and tweaks SDK1 is working inside our docker container which is running a linux os. What OS are you running on ?

Comment: I use WIN 10 OS

Comment: I have exactly same code with the environments different. How should I go about with debugging/fixing this? Can you give me some tips? I will try to test this with JDK 8 and winOS shortly

Comment: Test with Win OS and JDK 8 and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after adding a couple of dependencies for netty

implementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.40.Final'
implementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.40.Final'

I followed the https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/security/integrating-openssl.html to understand what was going on and why the netty.nio was having issues.